# Seeing if variable is in array

Tags: php, mysql

I am using a MySQL database. I am completely sure that the ID does actually exist in the database. Why is it going to the last else (where is says //incorrect id) ?

```
<?php
            //Localise user id.
            $userid = $_SESSION['userid'];

            //Get content of the article.
            $sql = "SELECT * FROM articles WHERE creatorid = '$userid'";
            $result = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error()); //Execute. If fails, show error.
            $array = mysql_fetch_array($result);

            if(in_array($articleid, $array)) //If the URL id exists in the database (array)
            {
                //The article does actually exist for that user. They requested it.
                $sql = "SELECT * FROM articles WHERE id = '$articleid'";                
                $result = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error()); //Execute. If fails, show error. 
                $array = mysql_fetch_array($result);

                        $content = $array['content'];

                        if($content != '') //If the article has actually been written.
                        {
                            include($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/includes/renderimage.php');
                        }   else
                            {
                                //Article actually hasn't been written.
                            }
            }   else
                {
                    //Incorrect ID.
                }
                ?>
```

Comment: where is `$articleid`? is it initialised? if not then else part will execute.

Comment: If I'm not wrong, you can't use `in_array` in that context. I have a gut feeling it doesn't iterate multiple dimensions.

Comment: Please don't use the `mysql_*` functions, they are no longer maintained and community has begun the [deprecation process](http://goo.gl/KJveJ) . Instead you should learn about [prepared statements](http://goo.gl/vn8zQ) and use either [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli). If you cannot decide, [this article](http://goo.gl/3gqF9) will help to choose. If you want to learn, [here is a good PDO-related tutorial](http://goo.gl/vFWnC).

Comment: $articleid is initialised in the script.     $articleid = $_GET['ref'];

Comment: add `var_dump($array);` and see what is in `$array`

Comment: so it should be shown in posted code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're only looking in the first row that's returned. You need to call `mysql_fetch_array` in a loop to get each row. Also, you shouldn't use `in_array()`, since the article ID might appear in some other column (what if you're checking for article #3 and user #3?).

But if you just want to see if the article was created by this user, you can use a different query:

```
SELECT * FROM articles WHERE creatorid = '$userid' AND articleid = '$articleid';
```

This should return either 0 or 1 row depending on whether the user created the article. You can then use `mysql_num_rows()` to test for this.

Answer (score 0):

It appears you are accessing the array incorrectly. On top of that you are returning multiple articles if the creator posted more than one so your in_array() is totally invalid. Change the limit on your query to one record (LIMIT 0,1) and access the creator id by calling:

```
$result[0]->creatorid or $result['creatorid']
```

depending on how your resource is queried